# How to find and replace for ranges with gsub

Tags: r

I have text as follows:

```
".OESOPHAGUS: inflammation. STOMACH: Lots of information here.DUODENUM: Some more information. ENDOSCOPIC DIAGNOSIS blabla"
```

I would like to replace any full stop followed by a letter (upper or lower case) to be replaced by a full stop, newline and then the letter. so that the output should be:

```
".\nOESOPHAGUS: inflammation. .\nSTOMACH: Lots of information here. .\nDUODENUM: Some more information. .\nENDOSCOPIC DIAGNOSIS blabla"
```

I tried:

```
gsub("\\..*?([A-Za-z])","\\.\n\\1",MyData$Algo)
```

but this gives me:

```
.\nESOPHAGUS: inflammation.\nTOMACH: Lots of information here.DUODENUM: Some more information.\nNDOSCOPIC DIAGNOSIS blabla"
```

The problem seems to be in the matching of ranges as specified. Is there a way to do this find-replace. I am not reliant on gsub.

Comment: try with `perl = T`

Comment: Thanks. Works well. Post as answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perl Compatible Regular Expressions (PCRE) should work well in this example.

```
a =  ".OESOPHAGUS: inflammation. STOMACH: Lots of information here.DUODENUM: Some more information. ENDOSCOPIC DIAGNOSIS blabla"

gsub("\\..*?([A-Za-z])","\\.\n\\1", a , perl = T)
#output:
".\nOESOPHAGUS: inflammation.\nSTOMACH: Lots of information here.\nDUODENUM: Some more information.\nENDOSCOPIC DIAGNOSIS blabla"
```

I am unsure why the lazy matching acts as it does when `perl = F`.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why you want `. .` instead of just `.\n`, this works for the latter:

```
gsub('[.]\\s*([a-zA-Z])', '.\n\\1', str)
# [1] ".\nOESOPHAGUS: inflammation.\nSTOMACH: Lots of information here.\nDUODENUM: Some more information.\nENDOSCOPIC DIAGNOSIS blabla"
```

When printed to console with `cat`, this looks like:

```
cat(gsub('[.]\\s*([a-zA-Z])', '.\n\\1', str))
# .
# OESOPHAGUS: inflammation.
# STOMACH: Lots of information here.
# DUODENUM: Some more information.
# ENDOSCOPIC DIAGNOSIS blabla
```

I can't explain either why `.*?` isn't doing what you want. But there's no reason to use `.` in this case, since you *do* have restrictions on the type of character you'd like to match between the full stop and the letter (I assumed white space `\s` would suffice).